# HSQLDB server connection using username and password in server startup command in cmd is not working

Tags: database, hsqldb, credentials, embedded-database, server-mode

i am starting hsqldb server with db_name as MDB and credentials as user=test and password=test using command prompt as:

```
    java -cp hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:/E:/DB/mdb --dbname.0 mdb user=test 
    password=test
```

it starts the server without error but when i use same credentials in my java code as

```
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/mware;file:E:/DB/mdb", "test", 
    "test");
```

it throws exception as:

```
 {java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: invalid authorization specification - not found: test
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)}
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to start the server is:

```
java -cp hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:/E:/DB/mdb;user=test;password=test --dbname.0 mware
```

And the connection should be like this:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/mware, "test", 
"test");
```

Any initial database settings in addition to `user` and `password` is defined the same way. For example `--database.0 file:/E:/DB/mdb;user=test;password=test;hsqldb.tx=mvcc`. The properties are applied to a new database and can be changed later with SQL statements. See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_db_operations

Comment: Thanks @fredt, its a nice way to go. I also tried it using your another post comment,  using java code as 
            p.setProperty("server.database.2", "file:G:/db1/mware;user=test;password=test");
            p.setProperty("server.dbname.2", "mware"); server.start(); and then Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"); and mentioned the connection url

Comment: Can you kindly tell me: Is there any way to mention "multithreading enabled" in In-Process:file mode database, or it is enabled by default in any encrypted in-proc:file type db.Following is my db url: getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\\inprocess\\mware;crypt_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;crypt_type=AES;crypt_lobs=false"

Comment: I have found this property hsqldb.tx=MVCC but will it help me in my multithreaded application performing diff operations on same/as well diff tables?

Comment: The MVCC mode is useful when there are a lot of writes at the same time as reads. If you are mostly reading from the tables, the default `locks` mode should be OK, Read the Guide.

Comment: (On time slot 1) My service is receiving data from multiple clients and I am writing in inprocess hsqldb also. While on another time(Time slot 2), I am reading the data from in-process db and getting the data to be written from another bunch of clients at the same time. So Should i use mvcc or locks?

Comment: If the duration of SQL INSERT and UPDATE statements is short, it doesn't matter. Otherwise MVCC is better.